Discord automation
How can I programmatically automate the process of detecting and accepting a call in Discord, as well as resetting it without using hotkeys (because, for example, in games, discord hotkeys do not work), machine vision, bots for channels in discord? It is necessary that the process of accepting a call to my personal account does not take up my time. For example, something like the toggle switch "automatically receive calls", the position of which I could change using the F12 key. Or your other ideas...
I tried to use reading packets coming from discord servers to detect an incoming call, but I didn't have enough knowledge to extract something useful from it, much less apply it.

Is the Discord GUI shown when receiving a call? Then you could use PyAutoGUI and write a small python script to automatically click on a given .png when it is shown on screen (i.e. pick-up call symbol) - function is called "locateOnScreen"

If you are very experienced you could try to enhance the "BetterDiscord" repository (https://github.com/BetterDiscord/BetterDiscord) and try to intercept with the call event to execute custom code

thanks for the tip from the github site, because of you.  Speaking of thanks for the tip with the repository on github, I'll study it! Speaking of "locateOnScreen", it will not work, because an unexpected call can interfere with work
